# Draw a pixel or point

Tags: python, svg

I'd like to draw a curve with svgwrite, I'd like to do it pixel by pixel because I'm doing some calculations on the coordinates.

How could I do it?

Comment: What do you mean with calculations and drawing? Tools like cairo draw curves themselves. You don't have to draw curves yourself to do calculations behind the curtains...

Comment: I'm playing around with bezier curves, I'd like to use svgwrite to draw them. Actually, I'm doing that, but I cannot draw only one pixel, I use lines, start point = x, end point = x + 1. It's ugly.

Comment: Drawing Bezier-curves is a recursive process. Instead of stopping at a certain level (in the call stack) you can check if the difference in length between the start and stop points is close to 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not really see how this help me out here.

Comment: You would get better looking results by drawing short connected line segments. SVG is vector-oriented and device-independent so the concept of device pixels doesn't exist -- all marks have a size. If you _really_ want to do something like this, you might be able create an raster image file and display that.

Comment: Also note that SVG has built-in commands to draw [cubic Bézier curves](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands).

Comment: Why not use Canvas? It's built for pixel pushing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to transform the Bezier curve to a set of points. Therefore you need to sweep with parameter `t=0` to `t=1`.

You can do this in such recursive way, where you for instance split values of `t` until they differ at most one pixel. Something like:

```
void bezier_recursive (double tfrom, double tto, Point relative, List<Point> points)
    double tmiddle = 0.5*(tfrom,tto));
    Point pt = bezier(tmiddle);
    if(length(pt,relative) > 1.0) {
        bezier_recursive(tfrom,tmiddle,pt,points);
        push(points,pt);
        bezier_recursive(tmiddle,tto,pt,points);
    }
}
```

As a result you will get a set of points and you can draw the as a sequence of lines.

Comment: Thank you! But I've already written the function to calculate the points, I even can draw them, but it is so ugly to use tiny lines instead of dots or pixels.

Comment: That's probably because svgwrite is not pixel-based. Svg's are vector based, meaning there is no such thing as a pixel. When you paint a circle, you only say "paint a circle with radius a", if you would for instance use a vectorscreen, you would get a "perfect" circle, some printers don't use the concept of pixels either. You should consider using another library to "paint" pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I simple used circles as dots, with a tiny radius.

Comment: You can also draw circles by first setting ``stroke-width` to small value (of course you can't really specify one pixel, see [Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#Units)) and the `stroke-linecap` style to `round`. Afterwards you can draw a zero-length path segment everywhere you want a dot to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using:

```
svg_document = svgwrite.Drawing(filename = "test-svgwrite.svg", size = ("800px", "600px"))

def draw_pixel(x,y,r,g,b):
    svg_document.add(svg_document.rect(insert = (x, y), size = ("1px", "1px"), fill = "rgb(%.0f,%.0f,%.0f)" % (r, g, b)))
```